# Rails routes, what's resources equivalent using match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rake

I have a question about the behaviour of my `routes.rb`. The following code works perfectly but it means that both `GET /noodles` and `GET /` will return the index of noodles. Because `noodles_path` will use `/noodles` the url becomes unnecessarily long, it keeps popping up.

```
root :to => 'noodles#index'
match '/new' => 'noodles#new', :as => :new_noodle, :via => [:get]
resources :noodles, :only => [:index, :create, :show]
```

In an attempt to remove the `GET /noodles` this I tried:

```
root :to => 'noodles#index'
match '/new' => 'noodles#new', :as => :new_noodle, :via => [:get]
resources :noodles, :only => [:create, :show]
match '/' => 'noodles#index', :as => :noodles, :via => [:get]
```

This does seem to work, but breaks the `:create` method somehow because they both have a `noodles` path and even though I specified it to `:get` only it gets confused (`rake routes` looks different, `noodles` is mentioned twice while when using `resources (...)` it's only mentioned once). So with these new routes it's impossible to create new noodles.

What's the correct way that removes `GET /noodles` for index and sets it to `GET /` while not breaking the `:create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its better to not mix non-resourceful routes with resourceful if you don't really need. And in this very case, you don't.

```
root :to => 'noodles#index'
resources :noodles
```

This is one you want, and you will have '/' and '/noodles' paths lead you to noodles#index, and that's what you suppose to want.

Take a look at your rake routes, you are creating something ugly ;) If you decide to curve out index route from noodles resource like in `resources :noodles, :except => :index`, you are also getting rid of noodles_path and noodles_url methods. The point of root is that you can change your mind about it, any time you want. Maybe it will be sign_up page, perhaps something different, maybe it wont change, but you don't want to loose that freedom.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the best solution would be to use `root_url` instead of `noodles_url` when trying to get to the index and using these routes

```
root :to => 'noodles#index'
resources :noodles, :except => :index
```

So basically this just creates all routes, except for `:index`, because this route already exists as `root`. Then in the views just use `root_url`.